# What actually response.on('data', function(data) {}); do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I want to understand what is happening under the hood on response.on("data").

When I request a web server, I get a response. And then I somehow use response.on("data" ...); and receive some kind of data. I want to know what data the program is taking.

For me it is like:

```
response {
  data {
    temperature: 50,
    city: "New York"
  }
  statusCode: 200
}
```

But that's not true, because then we could do just this: response.data and then take information from it.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage?

Comment: Are you talking about making a request as a client and receiving a response, or talking about receiving requests as a server and writing a response? If the former, you should remove the [[tag:express]] tag from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "data" thing is a [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) related event. It is not a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) or anything of [that sort](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/Data/exchange/formats/index). Put differently, when reading

```
response.on('data', function(data) {})
```

You should not fool yourself by thinking that the two mentions of "data" above are the same entities. They are related by design, but are two independent objects.

Comment: Any question @Phazerous ?

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense know. I know what my next steps are in Node JS. :-)